# Unable to build xamarin project to real device

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a Xamarin project (Visual Studio 2017). It's working fine in the emulator when run in Debug and Release mode but I am unable to run it in a real device as Visual Studio is not showing any attached device though device is already attached and also developer option and all necessary options are active.

I am also getting the following error when I try to make an APK and run it in a real device:

```
app not installed, package is corrupted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build it in release mode. Debug builds aren't signed. Then make an archive and distribute it (ad-hoc-mode). This will create a signed apk. More info: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/… – Andre Kraemer

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons for your issue that you don't see the device in the VS dropdown:

1. You have activated USB Debugging on your device but have not trusted the computer you're connecting to. Just try to deactivate and reactivate debugging. If a dialog appears that asks is you want to trust this computer, than this was your issue.
2. You have configured a minimum API Level / SDK Version for your app that is higher than the API Level of your device. So just check your Android version on your device and the version you've defined as minimum in your project settings

Regarding the "package corrupt" error, I can think of the following:

You have not signed your apk before you deployed it to the device. Just building the apk is not enough. There is an "archive" menu option in the context menu of your Android app. More info on that can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=vswin#archive-for-publishing

Comment: Compile using Android Version: Android 8.0(Oreo)
Minimum Android Version: Android 5.0(API 21, lollipop)
Target version: Android 8.0(API 26 , Oreo)

Comment: Here is the steps that i tried to install apk to my device:
1.Build Visual Studio solution in Debug mode(Just run on emulator).
2.Find the apk auto generate into the folder of the project.
3.Copy and paste the apk into my real device.
4.Then double click on that apk to install.Then i am getting error : "App not installed, The package appears to be corrupt"

Comment: Build it in release mode. Debug builds aren't signed. Then make an archive and distribute it (ad-hoc-mode). This will create a signed apk. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=vswin#archive-for-publishing

Comment: Thanks  @Andre Kraemer

Comment: You're welcome @PratimSahoo. If my answer helped you, please accept it

Comment: do you have any idea about what system codes are define inside "android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE"?